# How long does opening the Process tab in Build Definition file take for you

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In my project, opening the Process tab in my Build Definition file in VisualStudio 2013 and  2012 takes 2-3 minutes.

While opening its contents, the tab shows "Downloading custom assemblies".

Once it's completed, and the contents are displayed, I see various warnings and errors, like:

```
Summary: There were 0 failures, 404 errors and 15 warnings loading custom activities and services.
...
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Infrastructure.Interface, Version=1.0.3981.21634, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
...
Error: API restriction: The assembly 'file:///C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\8809fd18-08a3-4d58-8a87-35bbc833a4ed\1163529353\ThirdPartyBinaries\vjredist64\vjscor.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.
...
Warning: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\8809fd18-08a3-4d58-8a87-35bbc833a4ed\1163529353\ThirdPartyBinaries\SQLXML 4.0\cvtschema.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

*Can anybody advise what the problem is and how this can be resolved? Thanks.*

Comment: Are all of the assemblies with its dependencies checked in in your Repository

Comment: I will check.

The errors mention the assemblies, which I think, not used by the Process template. 

So this might result in the errors when the Process tab is being opened, it tries to find the assemblies mentioned, but not used.

Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the [TFS Client Cache](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/07/06/Clear-the-cache-of-TFS.aspx)? Also, are you the only one with this problem, or do other people see it?

Comment: David, thanks for help. 

No, I have not tried to clean the cache. I will read about it.

Other people also see the problem.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks again for your advice. I tried to clear TFS cache. But the problem still exists. I will investigate further.

Comment: Hi, stasde. Have you ever fixed this issue? I'm having a similar issue, where the "Queue Build" window takes 2-5min to display the Parameters tab. It keeps "Downloading custom assemblies..." for a while, everytime I try to open it.

Comment: Hi @TheFabricio. Yes, I have fixed the issue. Change the **Version control path to custom assemblies** in your in the TFS Build Controller: 

1. Open the **Properties** window of your Build Controller.
2. Set **Version control path to custom assemblies** to point to the folder in your source control where only the needed custom assemblies are located.


The performance problem occurred before because the **Version control path to custom assemblies** field pointed to a folder with lots of unnecessary sub-folders and assemblies. It took time to handle all of them.

Answer (score 1):

TFS build controllers and agents can have custom activities, and they download them from Source Control at the path indicated in the controller's `Version control path to custom assemblies` setting.

Since a template might use custom types from those custom assemblies, VS also needs them when you open `Edit Build Definition -> Process` or `Queue new build -> Parameters`. So VS downloads them, and unfortunately it doesn't have a local cache, so it downloads them every time. Also, VS loads the assemblies into the VS process, and that can incur `Could not load file or assembly...` errors.

The solution, as you've discovered, is to reduce the assemblies there to a minimum.